# Map crash or not responding address with C++ function name in sentry

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, sentry

I'm creating a product using Qt5 on Window 10 and I use Sentry to catch app crash or not responding event.
I want to know Function name of crash location, but sentry just return an address (picture).

I've tried searching but found no solution.
So, Can you give me a few suggestions with the questions below?

- How to catch not responding event with sentry?
- How to get function name of crash location in sentry board?

Address display in sentry.io:

[image: Address display in sentry.io]

Comment: https://blog.sentry.io/2019/05/23/native-crash-reporting-symbol-servers-pdbs-sdk-c-c-plus-plus

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings thanks! This article is very helpful to me. Can I ask you more?
Will sentry catch the app's not responding event?